# My giveaway cog command isn't working for some reason

Tags: discord.py

So I made a giveaway command in a cog, and for some weird reason it's not working. I'm not getting any errors or anything. Since it's "interactive", the first two questions work fine but once it asks for the prize, it just freezes and doesn't do anything after that. My friend is also working on a different bot and gave me his code which worked perfectly on his end, but not on mine. Here is my code:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import BucketType, cooldown, CommandOnCooldown
import random
import json
import datetime
import asyncio

class Giveaway(commands.Cog):
    """Giveaway commands. You must have manage message permissions to use these"""

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot



    # Helper functions

    def convert(self, time):
        pos = ["s", "m", "h", "d"]

        time_dict = {"s": 1, "m": 60, "h": 3600, "d": 2600*24}

        unit = time[-1]

        if unit not in pos:
            return -1
        try:
            val = int(time[:-1])
        except:
            return -2

        return val * time_dict[unit]



    # Bot Events



    # Bot Commands

    @commands.command()
    @commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
    async def giveaway(self, ctx, host: discord.Member):

        await ctx.send("Let's start with this giveaway! Answer these questions within 15 seconds!")

        questions = ["Which channel should it be hosted in?",
                     "What should be the duration of the giveaway? (s|m|h|d)",
                     "What is the prize of the giveaway?"]

        answers = [f"{ctx.channel.mention}"]

        def check(m):
            return m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.channel

        for i in questions:
            await ctx.send(i)

            try:
                msg = await self.bot.wait_for('message', timeout=15.0, check=check)
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                await ctx.send('You didn\'t answer in time, please be quicker next time!')
                return
            else:
                answers.append(msg.content)

        try:
            c_id = int(answers[0][2:-1])
        except:
            await ctx.send(f"You didn't mention a channel properly smh")
            return

        channel = self.bot.get_channel(c_id)

        time = convert(answers[2])

        prize = answers[3]

        await ctx.send(f"The giveaway for {prize} will be in {channel.mention} and will last {answers[2]}!! Hosted by {host.mention}")

        embed = discord.Embed(title="Giveaway!", description=f"{prize}", color=discord.Colour.dark_purple())

        embed.add_field(name="Hosted by:", value=f"{host}")

        embed.set_footer(text=f"Ends {answers[2]} from now!")

        my_msg = await channel.send(embed=embed)

        await my_msg.add_reaction("")

        await asyncio.sleep(time)

        new_msg = await channel.fetch_message(my_msg.id)

        users = await new_msg.reactions[0].users().flatten()
        users.pop(users.index(self.bot.user))

        winner = random.choice(users)

        await channel.send(f"Congratulations! {winner.mention} won the prize: {prize} from {host.mention}!!")



def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Giveaway(bot))
```

Please let me know what I should do to fix it!!

Comment: What is wrong? Any errors? There is too much code you put there, try to narrow down the issue

Comment: There are no errors, but everything works fine up until the question where it asks what the prize is. When you answer the question for that, i think the bot freezes? Or there must be something around there that it doesn't register because nothing after that works.